# Why does it not matter what mass of NaOH is used to solve for q?

Tags: thermodynamics, enthalpy

So we recently did a lab in Chem to prove Hess's law. The reactions we performed were

$$\begin{align}
\ce{NaOH + HCl &-> NaCl + H2O}\tag1\\
\ce{NaOH(s) + HCl &-> NaCl + H2O}\tag2\\
\ce{NaOH(s) &-> Na+ + OH- }\tag3
\end{align}$$

One of our post lab questions asks us to describe what would happen to the $q$ and $\Delta H$ of reaction $\text{(3)}$ if twice the mass of $\ce{NaOH(s)}$ were used.

For the third reaction, 4.1 degrees was the temperature change, 2 grams of $\ce{NaOH(s)}$ were used, and $50\ \mathrm{mL}$ of water were used. This gave me

$$q = (52~\mathrm g \times 4.18 \times 4.1) = -891.176 ~\mathrm J$$

and

$$\Delta H = (-891.176~\mathrm J/0.05~\mathrm{mol}) = -17824 ~\mathrm{J/mol}$$

When I used twice the mass of $\ce{NaOH(s)}$ like the problem asked, my results were

$$q = (54~\mathrm g \times 4.18 \times 4.1) = -925.452 ~\mathrm J$$

and

$$\Delta H = (-925.452/0.1~\mathrm{mol}) = -9225.908 ~\mathrm{J/mol}$$

Considering my results, why does the very next problem say that in reaction $\text{(3)}$, it doesn't really matter what mass of $\ce{NaOH}$ is used? Why would it not matter? My $\Delta H$ and $q$ values were different. I'm convinced that I made an error in my calculations, so I'd greatly appreciate some clarification here.

Also, it asks why is it important that $2\ \mathrm g$ of $\ce{NaOH}$ be used in reaction $\text{(2)}$? Is it because it's reacting with $\ce{HCl}$ instead of water like in reaction $\text{(3)}$?

Comment: Were you supposed to calculate the change in enthalpy **per mole** of reactant?

Comment: The temperature rise was exactly the same in both cases?

Comment: @JasonPatterson The question doesn't explicitly say that, but I think so.

Comment: @chestermiller The question just asks us to assume that twice the mass had been used. It makes no mention of other factors.

Comment: Well, you have to think that, if twice as much NaOH dissolved, more heat would be given off and the temperature change would be higher (in this case, about twice as high).

Comment: I don't understand your final question. *A priori* it is not important whether you use $2\,\mathrm{g}$ of $\ce{NaOH}$ or any other arbitrary amount. There have to be clues you’re not giving us.

Comment: What's the '4.18' mean, and why are you multiplying it by 52 g or 54 g? Units might help, especial ones which include "__ of  X", where X is water/NaOH/Na+/etc. The assumptions you're making here versus the ones the book is making might explain discrepancies.